# PHP strict standards error text added to results on the page

Tags: php

This is the error message generated:

> Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a
>   valid callback, non-static method
>   ModCareercoachoccupationsHelper::getRelated() should not be called
>   statically in
>   /customers/f/0/0/studiomitchell.agency/httpd.www/libraries/joomla/cache/controller/callback.php
>   on line 152

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Platform
 * @subpackage  Cache
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2016 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE
 */

defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;

/**
 * Joomla! Cache callback type object
 *
 * @since  11.1
 */
class JCacheControllerCallback extends JCacheController
{
    /**
     * Executes a cacheable callback if not found in cache else returns cached output and result
     *
     * Since arguments to this function are read with func_get_args you can pass any number of arguments to this method
     * as long as the first argument passed is the callback definition.
     *
     * The callback definition can be in several forms:
     * - Standard PHP Callback array see <https://secure.php.net/callback> [recommended]
     * - Function name as a string eg. 'foo' for function foo()
     * - Static method name as a string eg. 'MyClass::myMethod' for method myMethod() of class MyClass
     *
     * @return  mixed  Result of the callback
     *
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public function call()
    {
        // Get callback and arguments
        $args     = func_get_args();
        $callback = array_shift($args);

        return $this->get($callback, $args);
    }

    /**
     * Executes a cacheable callback if not found in cache else returns cached output and result
     *
     * @param   mixed    $callback    Callback or string shorthand for a callback
     * @param   array    $args        Callback arguments
     * @param   mixed    $id          Cache ID
     * @param   boolean  $wrkarounds  True to use wrkarounds
     * @param   array    $woptions    Workaround options
     *
     * @return  mixed  Result of the callback
     *
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public function get($callback, $args = array(), $id = false, $wrkarounds = false, $woptions = array())
    {
        // Normalize callback
        if (is_array($callback))
        {
            // We have a standard php callback array -- do nothing
        }
        elseif (strstr($callback, '::'))
        {
            // This is shorthand for a static method callback classname::methodname
            list ($class, $method) = explode('::', $callback);
            $callback = array(trim($class), trim($method));
        }
        elseif (strstr($callback, '->'))
        {
            /*
             * This is a really not so smart way of doing this... we provide this for backward compatability but this
             * WILL! disappear in a future version.  If you are using this syntax change your code to use the standard
             * PHP callback array syntax: <https://secure.php.net/callback>
             *
             * We have to use some silly global notation to pull it off and this is very unreliable
             */
            list ($object_123456789, $method) = explode('->', $callback);
            global $$object_123456789;
            $callback = array($$object_123456789, $method);
        }

        if (!$id)
        {
            // Generate an ID
            $id = $this->_makeId($callback, $args);
        }

        $data = $this->cache->get($id);

        $locktest             = new stdClass;
        $locktest->locked     = null;
        $locktest->locklooped = null;

        if ($data === false)
        {
            $locktest = $this->cache->lock($id);

            if ($locktest->locked == true && $locktest->locklooped == true)
            {
                $data = $this->cache->get($id);
            }
        }

        $coptions = array();

        if ($data !== false)
        {
            $cached                = unserialize(trim($data));
            $coptions['mergehead'] = isset($woptions['mergehead']) ? $woptions['mergehead'] : 0;
            $output                = ($wrkarounds == false) ? $cached['output'] : JCache::getWorkarounds($cached['output'], $coptions);
            $result                = $cached['result'];

            if ($locktest->locked == true)
            {
                $this->cache->unlock($id);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!is_array($args))
            {
                $referenceArgs = !empty($args) ? array(&$args) : array();
            }
            else
            {
                $referenceArgs = &$args;
            }

            if ($locktest->locked == false)
            {
                $locktest = $this->cache->lock($id);
            }

            if (isset($woptions['modulemode']) && $woptions['modulemode'] == 1)
            {
                $document = JFactory::getDocument();
                $coptions['modulemode'] = 1;
                if (method_exists($document, 'getHeadData'))
                {
                    $coptions['headerbefore'] = $document->getHeadData();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $coptions['modulemode'] = 0;
            }

            ob_start();
            ob_implicit_flush(false);

            $result = call_user_func_array($callback, $referenceArgs);
            $output = ob_get_clean();

            $coptions['nopathway'] = isset($woptions['nopathway']) ? $woptions['nopathway'] : 1;
            $coptions['nohead']    = isset($woptions['nohead']) ? $woptions['nohead'] : 1;
            $coptions['nomodules'] = isset($woptions['nomodules']) ? $woptions['nomodules'] : 1;

            $cached = array(
                'output' => ($wrkarounds == false) ? $output : JCache::setWorkarounds($output, $coptions),
                'result' => $result,
            );

            // Store the cache data
            $this->cache->store(serialize($cached), $id);

            if ($locktest->locked == true)
            {
                $this->cache->unlock($id);
            }
        }

        echo $output;

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Generate a callback cache ID
     *
     * @param   callback  $callback  Callback to cache
     * @param   array     $args      Arguments to the callback method to cache
     *
     * @return  string  MD5 Hash
     *
     * @since   11.1
     */
    protected function _makeId($callback, $args)
    {
        if (is_array($callback) && is_object($callback[0]))
        {
            $vars        = get_object_vars($callback[0]);
            $vars[]      = strtolower(get_class($callback[0]));
            $callback[0] = $vars;
        }

        return md5(serialize(array($callback, $args)));
    }
}
```

The site retrieves the data but with this text error also above 
the listing.

[image]

The callback.php line 152 is as follows:

```
$result = call_user_func_array($callback, $referenceArgs);
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: `ModCareercoachoccupationsHelper::getRelated()` is not a static method hence the error; instantiate an object and call `$object->getRelated()`

Comment: I am new to PHP could you be more specific where I need to add this code? I shall post the PHP

Answer (score 1):

You'll get this error if you define the method non-statically:

```
class Foo {
    public function bar() {
    }
}
```

And then define `$callback` as either a string:

```
$callback = 'Foo::bar';
```

Or an array of strings:

```
$callback = ['Foo', 'bar'];
```

And then use it as an argument to `call_user_func_array()`:

```
call_user_func_array($callback, []);
```

To avoid this, you can either define the method statically:

```
public static function bar() { ... }
```

Or use an instantiated object in your callback:

```
$callback = [new Foo(), 'bar'];
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for the answer - I am puzzled why this error is occurring as the site was functioning fine? I have posted the callback.php as I haven't a clue what I am doing.

Comment: Did you update your PHP version recently? I don't believe this used to be an E_STRICT violation in older versions.

Comment: Ah, yes we did. The site was produced in an older version. 5.3.27